# Site to site VPN - WatchGuard to Cisco - Unable to access one way

Tags: cisco, vpn

I've been racking my brains over this one today.

I've set up a site-to-site VPN connection between my primary site (Site1) and my secondary site (Site2). Each site is using a different subnet / network range. The tunnel is up and running.

Site1 is using a WatchGuard M200. Site2 uses a Cisco ASA 5500.

Site1 subnet is: 192.168.100.0/24

Site2 subnet is: 192.168.1.0/24

I can access web pages hosted on servers at Site2 from clients at Site1. However, I am unable to access web pages hosed on servers at Site1 from clients on Site2.

When I run a test the Cisco Packet Tracer tool, it fails at the access-list section on the Outside interface.

192.168.1.3 is the IP address of a client at Site2. 192.168.100.2 is the IP address of a server hosting a simple website on port 443 at Site1.

I can see from the results of the packet tracer that the connection is being dropped due to the implicit deny rule.

The firewall access rules on the Cisco at Site2 are:

[image]

I can't work out what rule I need to add in order to allow communication from Site2 to Site1 (as opposed to just Site1 to Site2 as it is at the moment).

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** ASA Config:

```
: Saved
: 
: Serial Number: [HIDDEN]
: Hardware:   ASA5505, 512 MB RAM, CPU Geode 500 MHz
:
ASA Version 9.2(4) 
!
hostname IS-49133
enable password [HIDDEN] encrypted
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain
passwd [HIDDEN] encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
 speed 100
 duplex full
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/5
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif Inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif Outside
 security-level 0
 ip address [SITE2 IP] 255.255.255.248 
!
boot system disk0:/asa924-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone GMT/BST 0
clock summer-time GMT/BDT recurring last Sun Mar 1:00 last Sun Oct 2:00
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 8.8.8.8
 name-server 8.8.4.4
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
object network IS-49110-ipmi-p
 host 192.168.1.2
object network IS-49110-p
 host 192.168.1.3
object network IS-49109-ipmi-p
 host 192.168.1.4
object network IS-49109-p
 host 192.168.1.5
object network IS-491010-ipmi-v
 host [Public IP 2]
object network IS-49110-v
 host 109.169.52.132
object network IS-49109-ipmi-v
 host [Public IP 3]
object network IS-49109-v
 host [Public IP 5]
object network InsideNetworkRange
 range 192.168.1.21 192.168.1.254
object network 192.168.1.10
 host 192.168.1.10
object network 192.168.1.11
 host 192.168.1.11
object network 192.168.1.12
 host 192.168.1.12
object network 192.168.1.13
 host 192.168.1.13
object network 192.168.1.14
 host 192.168.1.14
object network [Public IP 6]
 host [Public IP 6]
object network [Public IP 7]
 host [Public IP 7]
object network [Public IP 8]
 host [Public IP 8]
object network [Public IP 9]
 host [Public IP 9]
object network [Public IP 10]
 host [Public IP 10]
object network 192.168.1.15
 host 192.168.1.15
object network [Public IP 11]
 host [Public IP 11]
object network WG-HONetwork
 subnet 192.168.100.0 255.255.254.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_23
 subnet 192.168.100.0 255.255.254.0
object-group protocol TCPUDP
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 network-object host 192.168.1.4
 network-object host 192.168.1.5
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2
 network-object host 192.168.1.4
 network-object host 192.168.1.5
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
 network-object host [EXT IP]
 network-object host [SITE1 IP]
access-list basic extended permit tcp object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 any4 eq 3*** 
access-list basic extended permit tcp any4 any4 eq 3389 inactive 
access-list basic extended permit tcp host [SITE1 IP] any4 eq ssh 
access-list basic extended permit tcp any4 any4 eq www 
access-list basic extended permit tcp any4 any4 eq https 
access-list basic extended permit icmp any4 any4 
access-list basic extended permit object-group TCPUDP any4 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 eq 5*** 
access-list basic extended permit object-group TCPUDP any4 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2 eq 5*** 
access-list allow extended permit ip any4 any4 
access-list allow extended permit icmp any4 any4 
access-list Outside_cryptomap_2 extended permit ip 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.0 255.255.254.0 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu Inside 1500
mtu Outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-752-153.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (Inside,Outside) source static IS-49110-ipmi-p IS-491010-ipmi-v
nat (Inside,Outside) source static IS-49110-p IS-49110-v
nat (Inside,Outside) source static IS-49109-ipmi-p IS-49109-ipmi-v
nat (Inside,Outside) source static IS-49109-p IS-49109-v
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.10 [Public IP 6]
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.11 [Public IP 7]
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.12 [Public IP 8]
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.13 [Public IP 9]
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.14 [Public IP 10]
nat (Inside,Outside) source static 192.168.1.15 [Public IP 11]
nat (Inside,Outside) source dynamic InsideNetworkRange interface
nat (Inside,Outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.1.0_24 destination static NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_23 NETWORK_OBJ_192.168.100.0_23 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
access-group allow in interface Inside
access-group allow out interface Inside
access-group basic in interface Outside
access-group allow out interface Outside
route Outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [Gateway IP] 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL 
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
http server enable
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Outside
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES-MD5
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map Outside_map0 1 match address Outside_cryptomap_2
crypto map Outside_map0 1 set peer [SITE1 IP] 
crypto map Outside_map0 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA
crypto map Outside_map0 interface Outside
crypto ca trustpoint _SmartCallHome_ServerCA
 no validation-usage
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain _SmartCallHome_ServerCA
 certificate ca 6ecc7aa5a7032009b8cebcf4e952d491
    308205ec 308204d4 a0030201 0202106e cc7aa5a7 032009b8 cebcf4e9 52d49130 
    6119b5dd cdb50b26 058ec36e c4c875b8 46cfe218 065ea9ae a8819a47 16de0c28 
    6c2527b9 deb78458 c61f381e a4c4cb66
  quit
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption 3des
 integrity md5
 group 5
 prf md5
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 2
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable Outside
crypto ikev1 enable Outside
crypto ikev1 policy 1
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash md5
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 5
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Inside
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Outside
ssh timeout 60
ssh version 2
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 l2tp-ipsec ssl-clientless
group-policy GroupPolicy_[SITE1 IP] internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_[SITE1 IP] attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 
username admin password Gq4Kud5aGC668/VE encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group [SITE1 IP] type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group [SITE1 IP] general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_[SITE1 IP]
tunnel-group [SITE1 IP] ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
!
Cryptochecksum:cb42c61d05f6a55ebb5e5e94805f7e04
: end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the ASA configuration.

Comment: Done. Pastebin link added.

Comment: @OPGailey I have pasted the configuration into pre-formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Site2 (Cisco ASA 5500), looks like you applied the packet-tracer on *wrong* `Input interface: Outside`, that is why it was dropped. The correct interface should be Inside interface (or the interface where 192.168.1.3 generates the traffic).

Run the packet-tracer again with correct input interface and let us know the result. Also, please edit your question with the ASA configuration.

**Updated answer:**

The output of packet-tracer shows that the issue was at NAT rules. Once we moved the No-NAT rule (for VPN traffic) to the 1st position and PAT rule for Internet traffic at the end of NAT section, Site2 can access Site1.

Comment: When I try it with the Inside interface, using source: internal IP at Site2 and destination: internal IP at Site1, it works.   When I do the same with source: internal IP at Site1 and destination: internal IP as Site2, it fails at the VPN stage.   https://i.imgur.com/6sdwjHR.png

Comment: @OPGailey "with the Inside interface, using source: internal IP at Site2 and destination: internal IP at Site1, it works" => Correct and this is what we should test/expect with VPN setup.  Your inside interface is where Site2 internal IPs reside, not Site1 internal IPs (which is located outside), when you put them in WRONG source/destination order in 2nd/later packet-tracer that do not match `Outside_cryptomap_2`, resulting DROP

Comment: @OPGailey Even when you try with packet-tracer with OUTSIDE interface -  source: internal IP at Site1 and destination: internal IP at Site2, it will drop also at VPN Phase, because this is VPN tunnel, we cannot do like this. For VPN tunnel, always run packet-tracer on inside/internal interfaces with correct source and desation IPs.

Comment: @OPGailey Can you please let me know if Site2 can access Site1? Or you just tested it our with packet-tracer only?

Comment: No, Site2 cannot access resources on Site1 (ie, I cannot access https : // 192.168.100.2 from Site2).

Comment: @OPGailey Your firewall configuration looks fine in terms of VPN tunnel setup. If Site1 can access Site2 and packet-tracer on Site2 (`packet-tracer input Inside tcp 192.168.1.3 56789 192.168.100.2 443`) also is working but 192.168.1.3 still could not access Site1 web server 192.168.100.2 then I can be sure that the issue is at WatchGuard and network at Site1. Check inbound ACL rules and routing there, also make sure that port 443/80 are listening on that web server 192.168.100.2.

Comment: Thanks for checking the config and confirming that is looks okay on the Cisco end. I've just checked the Site1 firewall and the status of the VPN tunnel and I've noticed that is is reporting as having received packets from Site2 but not **sent** any. https://i.imgur.com/EUCovrx.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66709/discussion-between-opgailey-and-hung-tran).